# using oneOf in haskell, errors in compiling

Tags: haskell, ghc, parsec

I'm a complete newbie at Haskell. 
I'm trying to compile this Haskell file I've downloaded but it's giving me some errors.

```
No instance for (Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char)
  arising from a use of 'letter' at Parse.lhs:649:26-31
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char)
In the first argument of '(<|>)', namely 'letter'
In the expression: letter <|> oneOf "_"
In the definition of 'firstAllowed':
  firstAllowed = letter <|> oneOf "_"
```

Not sure if this is enough, but here's the section of the code with the error:

```
parseIdent = do { str <- indent
                ; return (makeIdent str)
                } <?> "identifier"
  where firstAllowed = oneOf "_" <|> letter
```

Comment: Write yourself a Scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the part you quoted the local `firstAllowed` function doesn't seem to be used anywhere. What happens if you remove the `where` line?

Alternatively you could try to add this type signature to `firstAllowed`:

```
 where
    firstAllowed :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char
    firstAllowed = ...
```